# Selenium grid - Unending logs caused by SO_TIMEOUT

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

We have around 1000+ tests running with 5 threads in parallel. Occasionally, the tests gets terminated due to low memory space. After analyzing, the selenium logs are occupying over 50GB+ of space. Looking at the recent logs, there is one single session(`e89da8f94eab2508559843f70803415f`) getting the Timeout issue causing the pileup. The logging time interval is in milliseconds, and its been throwing these errors for over 7 hrs before its failed due to space issue from jenkins server.

Doesn't the hub timeout handle the session to clear in case of SO_TIMEOUT?

Error log (Snippet):

```
E, [2018-01-19T12:17:23.395054 #15820] ERROR -- : Session [e89da8f94eab2508559843f70803415f] was terminated due to SO_TIMEOUT occurred
E, [2018-01-19T12:17:23.397025 #15820] ERROR -- : Session [e89da8f94eab2508559843f70803415f] was terminated due to SO_TIMEOUT occurred
E, [2018-01-19T12:17:23.398804 #15820] ERROR -- : Session [e89da8f94eab2508559843f70803415f] was terminated due to SO_TIMEOUT occurred
E, [2018-01-19T12:17:23.401062 #15820] ERROR -- : Session [e89da8f94eab2508559843f70803415f] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.
Active sessions are[ext. key 17cd8ad8-8d72-436e-a303-e7cad769f6a3, ext. key e7754f84-f20f-41e8-ba61-f1b8abc00756, ext. key 79d3617f201bf5b921af8c3aee20a25d, ext. key 62e38b838657b40334c1aa9035efd82d, ext. key d51b43f4636c4f45c74d770f1d8c03bf, ext. key 5afe975122fe6506473558bb43495d11, ext. key 886f3154-ea9b-4a7e-8133-acbaa16a809d, ext. key 35fcade3-454a-46ce-8688-e6b57dc8c6a9, ext. key 1e0257fdca0b4e5982d42622c4d763bf, ext. key f2ed3bd750ea18eeb863d16ec77609fe, ext. key 0752ea6f-9733-4a6d-9274-4dc607e2ca2f, ext. key 03ca2dd4-bf67-4888-8af1-6ae49741df4f, ext. key dc6b020a-96d6-40cf-830e-5742eddf2506, ext. key 86efe048-5785-4125-ba40-2f81595b5fa0, ext. key 4abcae379ef7e7ba1929806fd96607e1, ext. key b55695afa4eb60fd0cfd1801711ac881, ext. key 9a0a9cb7-131a-42de-b514-9d67118d2266, ext. key c7081f47-257a-4d2f-bdd5-c15ae0543e31, ext. key 4e8ec341-1f28-4454-a784-e80ac03fdbfc, ext. key 447c039560c4fa04ec0ad980c36c17e6, ext. key 5b55b421-539c-4d85-9c80-fc3c7a665ae0, ext. key 7da1fd2c-95b4-43e1-b8e0-364e9a5f22a9, ext. key 01340d8e-2572-4b3e-92f3-4fd31466954e, ext. key 533e313f-7a9d-4c10-9b1c-7c18418242d4, ext. key ac243cf84253ccca7bee1acc67150f1a, ext. key 9e386d25-0e55-46b1-ab19-3e3d68211c7f, ext. key 919ec8a9-4bf2-4a25-87d4-6d4d1f5d4099, ext. key f49f523e10c71ae73528639d78d80b14] occurred
E, [2018-01-19T12:17:23.401154 #15820] ERROR -- : Lux error message: Session [e89da8f94eab2508559843f70803415f] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.
Active sessions are[ext. key 17cd8ad8-8d72-436e-a303-e7cad769f6a3, ext. key e7754f84-f20f-41e8-ba61-f1b8abc00756, ext. key 79d3617f201bf5b921af8c3aee20a25d, ext. key 62e38b838657b40334c1aa9035efd82d, ext. key d51b43f4636c4f45c74d770f1d8c03bf, ext. key 5afe975122fe6506473558bb43495d11, ext. key 886f3154-ea9b-4a7e-8133-acbaa16a809d, ext. key 35fcade3-454a-46ce-8688-e6b57dc8c6a9, ext. key 1e0257fdca0b4e5982d42622c4d763bf, ext. key f2ed3bd750ea18eeb863d16ec77609fe, ext. key 0752ea6f-9733-4a6d-9274-4dc607e2ca2f, ext. key 03ca2dd4-bf67-4888-8af1-6ae49741df4f, ext. key dc6b020a-96d6-40cf-830e-5742eddf2506, ext. key 86efe048-5785-4125-ba40-2f81595b5fa0, ext. key 4abcae379ef7e7ba1929806fd96607e1, ext. key b55695afa4eb60fd0cfd1801711ac881, ext. key 9a0a9cb7-131a-42de-b514-9d67118d2266, ext. key c7081f47-257a-4d2f-bdd5-c15ae0543e31, ext. key 4e8ec341-1f28-4454-a784-e80ac03fdbfc, ext. key 447c039560c4fa04ec0ad980c36c17e6, ext. key 5b55b421-539c-4d85-9c80-fc3c7a665ae0, ext. key 7da1fd2c-95b4-43e1-b8e0-364e9a5f22a9, ext. key 01340d8e-2572-4b3e-92f3-4fd31466954e, ext. key 533e313f-7a9d-4c10-9b1c-7c18418242d4, ext. key ac243cf84253ccca7bee1acc67150f1a, ext. key 9e386d25-0e55-46b1-ab19-3e3d68211c7f, ext. key 919ec8a9-4bf2-4a25-87d4-6d4d1f5d4099, ext. key f49f523e10c71ae73528639d78d80b14] occurred
E, [2018-01-19T12:17:23.402993 #15820] ERROR -- : Session [e89da8f94eab2508559843f70803415f] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.
```

Env:
Selenium grid 3.7.0

Hub settings:

```
 {
  "port": 4444,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlets": [
    "com.groupon.seleniumgridextras.grid.servlets.ProxyStatusJsonServlet"
  ],
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "browserTimeout": 300,
  "timeout": 300,
  "maxSession": 35
```

Node config:

```
    {
  "capabilities": [
    {
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "maxInstances": 3,
      "version": "57",
      "platform": "win7"
    },
    {
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "browserName": "internet explorer",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "version": "11",
      "platform": "win7"
    },
    {
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 4,
      "version": "62",
      "platform": "win7"
    }
  ],
  "loadedFromFile": "node_5555.json",
  "proxy": "com.groupon.seleniumgridextras.grid.proxies.SetupTeardownProxy",
  "servlets": [],
  "maxSession": 7,
  "port": 5555,
  "register": true,
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 10000,
  "hubPort": 4444,
  "hubHost": "xxxxyyyyy.com",
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 10000,
  "custom": {},
  "downPollingLimit": 0
}
```

Comment: Something in your test code is repeatedly attempting to clean up the session with the session id "e89da8f94eab2508559843f70803415f" by invoking the quit() method repeatedly. Have you tried finding out what that is ?

Comment: I say this because [ActiveSessions.getExistingSession](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.7.0/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/internal/ActiveTestSessions.java#L97-L112) which is where the error message arises is called only when [RequestHandler.process()](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.7.0/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/web/servlet/handler/RequestHandler.java#L122) is called.

Comment: I forget to mention, that is a cucumber test where it is using scenario outline. So the same session is being shared by all the test cases. I have gone through each step before the failure, i couldn't figure out where the infinite loop getting in.

Comment: Also, shouldn't the grid/node fail the test once it hits the SO_TIMEOUT?

Comment: The Grid is a remote JVM. It has no control whatsoever on your tests which is ruby based. All that can be done by the grid is to throw exceptions and abort that particular operation. So you can rule out the test failure due to `SO_TIMEOUT`. So if the same test session is being used by all your tests, you might want to start from there. The code base indicates that this error message can be only seen when you have a `driver.quit()` invoked.

Comment: Oh, i was expecting the grid to end the session, understood now. Thanks @KrishnanMahadevan I will dig more into the code. Since the code base is maintained by folks across the org it is a bit of work :)

Comment: If you are happy with that response, I would add it as an answer so that you can accept it and we can close this question. Please let me know

Comment: I will investigate this further based on your inputs, please add this as an answer, this should be helpful to others as well

Comment: Please add a comment to let me know how it went. Based on that I will add an answer and you can accept it as well.